# trying to combine these two json arrays in php

Tags: php, json, array-merge

I've tried things like `json_combine` and `array_merge` but I can't figure out how to do this.

```
  $query2 = "SELECT DISTINCT cat_id,cat_name FROM review WHERE user_id = ? AND public_or_private = 0";
    $stmt2 = $con->prepare($query2) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    $stmt2->bind_param('i', $user_id) or die ("MySQLi-stmt binding failed ".$stmt2->error);
    $stmt2->execute() or die ("MySQLi-stmt execute failed ".$stmt2->error);
    $result2 = $stmt2->get_result();

                    $array1 = array();

                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {

                        $array1['results'][] = $row;

                    }

echo json_encode($array1);
```

The `json_encode` gives me:

```
{"results":[{"cat_id":4,"cat_name":"dentist"}]}
```

And further down in my code I have:

```
$query3 = "SELECT DISTINCT cat_id,cat_name FROM review WHERE public_or_private = 2";
                $result3 = mysqli_query($con,$query3);

                $array2 = array();

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3)) {

                $array2['results'][] = $row;

                }  

echo json_encode($array2);
```

The `json_encode` gives me:

```
{
    "results": [{
        "cat_id": "8",
        "cat_name": "dental hygienist"
    }, {
        "cat_id": "5",
        "cat_name": "stocktaker"
    }, {
        "cat_id": "9",
        "cat_name": "builder"
    }]
}
```

So in total I have two json arrays:

```
{
    "results": [{
        "cat_id": 4,
        "cat_name": "dentist"
    }]
} 

{
    "results": [{
            "cat_id": "8",
            "cat_name": "dental hygienist"
        }, {
            "cat_id": "5",
            "cat_name": "stocktaker"
        },
        {
            "cat_id": "9",
            "cat_name": "builder"
        }
    ]
}
```

But how can I combine these into one like:

```
{
        "results": [{
                "cat_id": 4,
                "cat_name": "dentist"
            }, {
                "cat_id": "8",
                "cat_name": "dental hygienist"
            }, {
                "cat_id": "5",
                "cat_name": "stocktaker"
            },
            {
                "cat_id": "9",
                "cat_name": "builder"
            }
        ]
    }
```

I tried things like:

```
 $jsonArray = array();
foreach (array_combine( $array1, $array2 ) as $name => $value) {
    $jsonArray[] = array('cat_id' => $name, 'cat_name' => $value);
}

echo $json = json_encode($jsonArray);
```

but still couldn't get it to work properly.

Comment: Why not reuse `$array1` for both cases?

Comment: why not merge them before you json_encode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to use `array_merge_recursive` instead.

```
echo json_encode(array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2));
```

Answer (score 2):

Its not `array_combine`
You need to merge both array

```
$array1 = json_decode($array1, true);
$array2 = json_decode($array2, true);
$final_array =  array_merge($array1['results'], $array2['results']);
```

Comment: For the exact structure in the question it should probably be: `$final_array['results'] =  array_merge...`. But the rest is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have your arrays, you can do this:

```
$res1 = [
    "results"=> [[
        "cat_id"=> 4,
        "cat_name"=> "dentist"
    ]]
]; 

$res2 = [
    "results"=> [[
            "cat_id"=> "8",
            "cat_name"=> "dental hygienist"
        ], [
            "cat_id"=> "5",
            "cat_name"=> "stocktaker"
        ],
        [
            "cat_id"=> "9",
            "cat_name"=> "builder"
        ]
    ]
];

$combinedArray = array_merge_recursive($res1, $res2);
$jsonCombinedArray = json_encode($combinedArray);
```

This results into

```
{
  "results": [
    {"cat_id":4,"cat_name":"dentist"},
    {"cat_id":"8","cat_name":"dental hygienist"},
    {"cat_id":"5","cat_name":"stocktaker"},
    {"cat_id":"9","cat_name":"builder"}
  ]
}
```